# Static message above the page in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a web page with lengthy contents. I just want to put some message at the bottom of the browser window and this message should always be visible even if you scroll down the page.

can you guys tell me how to go that with simple css, html, jquery or in PHP

thanks

Answer (score 5):

I do believe it would be:

```
.status_bar {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

If you need it to work in IE 6, then I recommend checking out [this fix](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/fixed.html) (I'm on a linux machine right now without access to IE 6, so I cannot say for sure -- but I've generally found Stu Nicholls to have correct fixes to obscure browser bugs.)

Answer (score 2):

try using a sticky footer. code is at http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 500px">
    ... your content here ..
</div>
```

Note: doesn't work in IE6